# Scene is not the function in flutter code

Tags: flutter

Here is the image of the error:

[image: Here is the image of the error]

What is the solution to this error? I tried to write here the 'Row" function but the emulator is not opening the application.

Answer (score 0):

Scene class is coming from **dart:ui** library.

```
import 'dart:ui';
```

After importing this library, you'll see another error msg. Such as `The argument type 'Scene' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'`.

Because you're trying to pass `Scene` as a `widget` based on your **SS** code. Actually it's an `object`(ig). Follow the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Scene-class.html) to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are importing Scene from 2 librairies: android-small-7.dart and 8. If you need both imports, use an alias. Otherwise remove one of the librairies.